# How can I add the following stochastic elements to my simulation of a multiple machine with buffer system?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I have gotten a few steps further along with my simulation and analysis of the machines that I want to simulate. As of now I am stuck and do not for the life of my know how to go further.

I have decided to add stochastic elements to my machine. Before (see code below) I had a Machine class that has *produce, failure* and *repair* process. My professor and I have decided that using stochasticity will be a better representation of reality. Therefore I have the following elements I would like to add and explanation of the process:

1. All Machines starts in state 1
2. Every second (tick) a *processing speed* is chosen from possibilities (% chance)
3. Immediately a *time in state* is chosen from distribution (or `random.choice()` for ease of use)
4. After the *time in state* has passed, a new state is chosen from possibilities (% chance)
5. The process repeats until simulation time is over.

There is no more machine failure and repair process as this is taken up in the different states.

I have an idea that I will need to make 3 functions, for determining *state, speed* and *time in state* only I have no idea how to do this.

The different parameters/possibilities per machine are as follows:

**Machine 1**

If in state 1:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 3: 54%, 4: 24%, 5  : 22% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 0: 41%, 2: 54%}

If in state 2:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 2: 90%, 0: 10% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 0: 60%, 1: 40%}

If in state 0:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 0: 100% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 1: 100% }

**Machine 2**

If in state 1:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 5: 42%, 4: 34%, 7  : 24% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 0: 70%, 2: 30%}

If in state 2:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 1: 80%, 0: 20% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 0: 90%, 1: 10%}

If in state 0:

- Possible speeds (in ticks): { 0: 100% }
- Duration: Exponential distribution or `random.choice()`
- Possible next state after duration: { 1: 100% }

Any help will be much much appreciated!

I am adding the code of my simulation as I have it now. I do know that a few elements are obsolete due to now needing to fail and repair anymore but I am not sure how to change it up.

```
# Parameters for the Machines
# Machine 1
speed_1 = 0.1          # Avg. processing time of Machine 1 in minutes
# speed_1_stdev = 0.6  # St. dev. of processing time of Machine 1
MTTF_1 = 9          # Mean time to failure Machine 1
# fail_1 = 1/MTTF_1    # Parameter for exp. distribution
repair_1 = 5         # Time it takes to repair Machine 1

# Machine 2
speed_2 = 0.15         # Processing time of Machine 2 in minutes
# speed_2_stdev = 0.6  # St. dev. of processing time of Machine 2
MTTF_2 = 7           # Mean time to failure Machine 2
# fail_2 = 1/MTTF_2    # Parameter for exp. distribution
repair_2 = 3         # Time it takes to repair Machine 2


# Simulation time
time = 60           # Sim time in minutes

# Class setup for a Machine
class Machine(object):
    """
    A machine produces units at a fixed processing speed, 
    takes units from a store before and puts units into a store after.

    Machine has a *name*, a processing speed *speed*, a preceeding buffer *in_q*,
    and a proceeding buffer *out_q*.
    """
    def __init__(self, env, name, in_q, out_q, speed, mttf, repair):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.in_q = in_q
        self.out_q = out_q
        self.speed = speed
        self.mttf = mttf
        self.repair = repair
        self.broken = False
        self.count = 0

        # Start the producing process
        self.process = env.process(self.produce())
        # Start the failure process
        env.process(self.fail_machine())
    
    def produce(self):
        """
        Produce parts as long as the simulation runs. 
        It is prone to breaking down and being repaired.
        """
        
        while True:
            pspeed = self.speed  
            try:
                yield env.timeout(pspeed)
                if len(self.out_q.items) >= self.out_q.capacity:
                    pspeed = 0
                    print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  {self.name} output buffer full!!!')
                    # Add the "Tailback" status to the event list
                    event_list.append({"Time": self.env.now, "Machine": self.name, 
                                       "State": "Tailback", "Speed": pspeed, 
                                       "Count": self.count, "Tailback": 1})
                else:
                    pspeed = self.speed
                    part = yield self.in_q.get()
                    yield self.out_q.put(part)
                    self.count += 1
                    # Add the "Running" status to the event list
                    event_list.append({"Time": self.env.now, "Machine": self.name, 
                                       "State": "Running", "Speed": pspeed, 
                                       "Count": self.count, "Tailback": 0})
            
            except simpy.Interrupt:  # This ensures that the machine breaks down
                self.broken = True
                pspeed = 0
                yield self.env.timeout(self.repair)
                print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} {self.name} is fixed')
                # Add the "Repaired" event notification to the event list
                event_list.append({"Time": self.env.now, "Machine": self.name, 
                                   "State": "Repaired", "Speed": pspeed, 
                                   "Count": self.count, "Tailback": 0})
                self.broken = False
                pspeed = self.speed
                env.process(self.fail_machine())
        
    def fail_machine(self):
        """
        The machine is prone to break down every now and then.
        """
        yield self.env.timeout(self.mttf)
        pspeed = 0
        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} {self.name} is in failure.')
        # Add the "Failure" event notification to the event list
        event_list.append({"Time": self.env.now, "Machine": self.name, 
                           "State": "Failure", "Speed": pspeed, 
                           "Count": self.count, "Tailback": 0})
        if not self.broken:
            # Machine only fails if currently working.
            self.process.interrupt(self.mttf)

# Generating the arrival of parts in the entry buffer to be used by machine 1
def gen_arrivals(env, entry_buffer):
    """
    Start the process for each part by putting
    the part in the starting buffer
    """
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(0,0.0001))
        # print(f'{env.now:.2f} part has arrived')
        part = object() # Too lazy to make a real part class, also isn't necessary

        yield entry_buffer.put(part)

# Print the status of the number of processed parts per machine every minute
def print_status(env, machine, period):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(period)
        print(f"{env.now}: {machine.name} has outputted {machine.count}")

# Create environment and start the setup process
env = simpy.Environment()
bufferStart = simpy.Store(env)  # Buffer with unlimited capacity
buffer1 = simpy.Store(env) # Buffer between machines with unlimited capacity
bufferEnd = simpy.Store(env)  # Last buffer with unlimited capacity

# The machines __init__ starts the machine process so no env.process() is needed here
machine_1 = Machine(env, 'Machine 1', bufferStart, buffer1, speed_1, MTTF_1, repair_1)
machine_2 = Machine(env, 'Machine 2', buffer1, bufferEnd, speed_2, MTTF_2, repair_2)


# Process necessary to run all events
env.process(gen_arrivals(env, bufferStart))
env.process(print_status(env, machine_1, 1))
env.process(print_status(env, machine_2, 1))

# Dictionary to log events
event_list = [{"Time": 0.00, "Machine": "All", 
               "State": "Simulation start", 
               "Speed": 0, "Count": 0, "Tailback": 0}]
# Execute
env.run(until = time)
```

Comment: I would write a process for each state where the last thing the process does is use env.process (no yield) to start the next state.  The random package has a lot of good stuff including distributions.

Comment: in your old code, why can you not used a distribution in your env.timeout() instead of your fix number.  using the random package a example would be env.timeout(random.expovariate(1/mean_time)   that would add some stochastic ness

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. For your first comment: I am not sure I totally understand. Is what you are mentioning for the duration in current state? Or can it be used for all the parameters? I believe that I could write a function where for example: Machine 1 speed: if x <= 54 speed is 3, if x <=78 speed = 4 and if x <= 100 speed = 5. But then still no idea how to implement this. 


For your second comment: I wont be using the fixed numbers. The code is just where I am at now but the speed, MTTF and repair need to be replaced with speed (%), duration and next state (%).

Comment: I'm not sure what I am missing.  everyplace there is a constant just replace it with a function to calculate the a sample from a distribution or weighted list.  for example speed = randaom.choices(]3,4,5], cum_weights=[54,78,100])[0]

Comment: Ah I did not realize it's that easy for speeds. Then I guess my follow up question would be how to incorporate the state change. Or do I just edit the `def fail_machine` to account for that?

Comment: If I try it like this I get an error stating: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. Do I have to create a new function for each of the parameter choices then? But I guess where my main question lies is the fact that the speeds are different for every state. So it needs to first determine the state that it is in and then based on the state determine the speed.

Comment: using a interrupt and exception handling is a pretty standard way to model a machine with breakdowns.  You just need to replace your constants with a function that is not constant values.  I'm still a little confused about what sates you need.  but you can have a state variable (or expand you broken flag) and us if statements to get the right function